# Refresh token for vue-adal

Tags: vue.js, azure-active-directory

I'm using [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) to build a SPA and [vue-adal](https://github.com/survirtual/vue-adal) to authenticate with Azure AD. Logging in works fine, but now I'm trying to keep the users logged in. I did some research and read that a refresh token would make this possible. I've read [here](https://github.com/survirtual/vue-adal/issues/2#issuecomment-376361328) that I have to create this functionality manually, but I can't really find anything useful about how to actually do that.
So how would I go on about refreshing my tokens in a SPA using vue.js / vue-adal?